# CarouselView.FormsPlugin not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, carousel

I have a Xamarin Forms project, where I use CarouselView's NuGet, and it works perfect for on Android, but on iOS it does not show.

I tried the version of Carousel 5.0.0 and 5.2.0

This is the Class AppDelegate

```
using CarouselView.FormsPlugin.iOS;

namespace FortiaApp.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            RoundedBoxViewRenderer.Init();
            AnimationViewRenderer.Init();
            CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code of my app

```
private View[] _views;
public frmDetalle(int idUsuario)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
            lblSaludo.Text = utileriasServices.getSaludo();
            lblFecha.Text = utileriasServices.getFecha();

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var response = await fortiaServices.PostAsinc<AccountModel>(new Account { IdUser = this.idUsuario }, "/GetInfoInit");
                if (response != null)
                {
                    this.accountModel = response;

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        var responseToken = await fortiaServices.PostAsinc<TokenApiResponse>(new Object(), "/GetToken");

                        if (responseToken != null)
                        {
                            this.accountModel.tokenApi = responseToken;
                            this.accountModel.idTarjeta = this.accountModel.account.idTarjetaPrincipal;

                            //Agrega tarjetas
                            _views = new View[accountModel.Tarjetas.Count + 1];
                            _views[0] = new frmTarjeta(this.accountModel, this.accountModel.idTarjeta);

                            for (var i = 0; i < accountModel.Tarjetas.Count; i++)
                            {
                                this.accountModel.idTarjeta = this.accountModel.Tarjetas[i].IdTarjeta;
                                _views[i + 1] = new frmTarjeta(this.accountModel, this.accountModel.Tarjetas[i].IdTarjeta);
                            }
                            Carousel.ItemsSource = _views;
                            await GetInfoPrincipal();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Tenemos problemas", "Los servicios no estan disponibles", "Continuar");
                            await Navigation.PushAsync(new frmLogin());
                        }
                    });

                    await Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PopModalAsync(false);
                    await DisplayAlert("Tenemos problemas", "Los servicios no estan disponibles", "Continuar");
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new frmLogin());
                }
            });
        }
```

And this is mi file xaml

```
xmlns:carousel="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"

 <carousel:CarouselViewControl
                            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height,Factor=.16,Constant=0}"
                            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
                            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=.42,Constant=0}"
                                    x:Name="Carousel"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Position="0"
                                    ShowIndicators="True"
                                    ShowArrows="False"                                    
                                    CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="#93B638"
                                    IndicatorsTintColor="White"
                                    PositionSelected="OnCarouselPositionSelected"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

This is how it looks on the two platforms, as you can see, on Android it works perfect, but on iOS the carousel is not shown
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any Application Output errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that putting the CarouselView inside a RelativeLayout didn't work for me. What did work is putting it in an AbsoluteLayout/Grid/StackLayout (I have not tried FlexLayout). I think it has to do with the view sizing, but I'm not sure.

Given the screenshots in your question, it looks like you can simplify your layout to use StackLayout. Doing so should allow the CarouselView to show up.